# C++ name lookup --

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

The standard says (brackets mine)

> In all the cases listed in 3.4.1 [Unqualified name lookup], the scopes are searched for a declaration in the order listed in each of the respective categories …

**Why would the names be kept in some sort of ordered list(s)?** After all, except for function overloading and name hiding, I think that names are unique within a namespace.

---

UPDATE to address a comment:

I would expect the compiler to keep the names defined in a container such as *unordered_set* per scope and scopes linked in a look up chain.

I was wondering why would the names be classified into lists per category (which I thought were variables, typedefs, structure like, functions, templates, etc.) and those lists further sorted.

Comment: What "ordered list" do you think exists, and why? It seems to me the "order" in the standard says nothing about putting things into lists during compilation: it is saying something about lists of descriptive sentences that are found later in that section of the standard.

Comment: [Names can be shadowed within scopes, which is where order is important](http://ideone.com/0J5iDn). Note that that code has three different variables, all named `x`. The program prints `2` because of the search order defined in the standard.

Comment: @DavidK: your interpretation of categories as "the cases listed in 3.4.1" seems more plausible than mine. What threw me off was that those items were called "cases" first and "categories" then. I did not think the standard would use synonyms to keep a natural flow of speech.

Comment: @Hector I too am surprised (not in a good way) by the way this part of the standard is worded.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The "order" in this case is not the order of the *names*. It is the order of the *scopes*. In each category the scopes are listed in certain order (typically "inside-out": from inner scopes to outer scopes). This is the order in which these scopes are searched. Typically, the first scope that contains the name in question causes the search to stop.